# Redirection after form submission and API call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a formular (on `page1.php`) on my website, where the user selects some informations (for instance a date and a place to go). I am using an API (**skyscanner**) to retrieve informations on flights according to the user informations. 
Once the user has clicked on the **OK** button I want to redirect him to a page (`page2.php`) of my website where I display the informations retrieved by the API call.

So, to get there I think I have 2 options:

Either I only use *JavaScript*, I make an API call with *XMLHttpRequest*, where I redirect (with **window.location** for instance) the user to `page2.php`. But the problem here is that I don't know if it's possible to retrieve the API response in the redirected page and how to do it (the response will be in JSON also...).

Or, I redirect the user with Php (`header('location` etc.) with the informations of the form in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` parameter, and **THEN** I make a call to the API (with *HMLHttprequest*) on `page2.php`.

So, what option should be the fastest ? or what is the best practice ?

I hope I was a bit clear in my explanations.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Fastest or best practice here is not important.  What is important is the framework you are working with and the rest of the application.  Either of the two options are acceptable.  In the javascript way, you redirect only after you receive the reply from the server.

Comment: @AleksG Hi, thank you, I am not working with a framework. So for the Javascript way how to pass the retrieved infos to `page2.php` ? is it possible to pass those info through the `window.location` function for instance ?

Comment: There are many ways of passing data, including url, sesssion, etc - search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't set page2.php in the form action? `<form method="GET" action="page2.php">` This way the form data directly send to the page2.php and there you can get the data using `$_GET['date']` and `$_GET['location']`